# Windows Explorer Shell Extension: recursive delete via ITransferSource::RemoveItem?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I'm implementing a Windows Explorer Shell Extension for a networked file system on Windows 7, and I've hit a snag while implementing the Delete functionality.

Let's say my remote filesystem hierarchy is as follows:

```
Dir1
+-Dir2
| +-A
| +-B
+-C
```

My understanding is that you need to implement `ITransferSource::RemoveItem` (which I've done), but I expected to be called recursively from the furthest child in the filesystem tree first (i.e. a depth-first recursive traversal):

```
(A, B, Dir2, C, Dir1)
```

What happens is that I'm called for the root first, then each children, iteratively:

```
(Dir1, C, Dir2, A, B)
```

This is a bit weird to me since the Shell will already recursively iterate through all items to be deleted in order to show the progress bar for the operation (the "discovering items" dialog). My remote filesystem does not support deleting non-empty directories; as far as I know, the local filesystem on Windows has the same limitation. I could not find any hints on MSDN about changing the iteration order.

I presume that the actual iteration order varies depending on the creation order of the items in the filesystem.

When implementing this interface method, you can return `COPYENGINE_S_DONT_PROCESS_CHILDREN` if you recurse and delete entire trees yourself, but I think this will not allow the user to Cancel a deletion in progress (like the standard Explorer shell would). I consider this a sub-optimal solution, but it may have to do if I don't find a better solution.

My first thought was to queue up the non-empty directory deletion requests for later, but I don't think this will work, because the extension will not know when the Delete operation for all children of a directory is completed. I could also spawn a thread to delete these items "later" but that's almost certain to create weird unexplained behaviors and crashes.

So, I guess my question is, what is the proper way to implement the Delete operation in a Windows 7 Shell Extension?

PS: as you can probably tell, Windows Shell Extensions are a completely new topic for me, so I apologize in advance if the question is incomplete; I will refine my question as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but ITransferSource has a pair of methods that seems to be designed for exactly this purpose: [EnterFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774516) and [LeaveFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774523).

Comment: Hey, this works! It doesn't fix the iteration order but the `EnterFolder` and `LeaveFolder` callbacks are called as I expect them to (Enter Dir1, Enter Dir2, Leave Dir2, Leave Dir1). You should add this comment as an answer so I can credit you for it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation it looks like the [EnterFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774516) and [LeaveFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774523) methods will help you out.

Comment: Thanks again, I had missed those methods in the doc. It's not exactly what I wanted but I can certainly work with that.

Comment: @BenoitMiller: How did you get to use those ? I'm in pretty much the same case, and neither EnterFolder and LeaveFolder are called for me. Moreover, I can't fathom how having them called would help for the deletion. Would you mind expanding a bit ?

Comment: In my handler for RemoveItem, if the deletion fails, I store the path of the folder elsewhere (state structure associated with the main object I'm browsing, not the PIDL). Then when LeaveFolder is called, if the path matches one I stored earlier, I know I have to retry the Delete request.

Comment: I didn't have any trouble having these methods called, I just return a pointer to an ITransferSource interface when IShellFolder2::CreateViewObject is called. Then when ITransferSource::LeaveFolder is called, I look up my own ptr for the passed shellitem and call a function that executes any pending operations (in my case the Delete that failed).